# how do I put a label and a UISwitch into a custom cell? I've researched and I'm not understanding, but it is similar to this picture below

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

[image: image of iOS simulator window on iphone retina 4 inch iOS7]

I've googled this answer multiple times and what I'm finding is not either working or doesn't make sense to me. Could anyone take a whack at this and help me out? Been stuck on this issue for hours.

Comment: click "enter image description here" to see what I mean.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Update your question with what you've done so far and explain what exact issue(s) you are having.

Comment: have you tried creating your custom cell??

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by not working? Just drag a tableview in the storyboard's view controller and then a UITableViewCell into it, followed by a UILabel and UISwitch. I've attached a screenshot.

[image]

Create a tableviewcell custom class, drag and link the switch and label into .h of the class file and that's it you'll get it working as simple as that.

[image]

Don't forget to link UITableview's 'datasource' and 'delegate' method's.

Answer (score 0):

Goto to CellForRowAtIndexPath in UITableView Delegate Method

Add this code it works for you

For UILabel:

```
var newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(280.0, 14.0, 300.0, 30.0)) //make frame according to your need
newLabel.text = newData[indexPath.row]
newLabel.tag = 1
```

for UISwitch:

```
var switchView: UISwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero)
aCell.accessoryView = switchView
switchView.setOn(false, animated: false)
switchView.addTarget(self, action: "switchChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKYld5QVJBZ1FqTFk/view?usp=sharing) custom cell with table view example.

There is label and switch.

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell : CustomCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ID_CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! CustomCell

    cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    cell.lblData.text = myArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("Data") as? String

    if let str = myArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("Data") as? String
    {
         cell.lblData.text = str as String

    }

    cell.switch1.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.switch1.addTarget(self, action: "switchChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)


    return cell

}

func switchChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {

    let no = mySwitch.tag
    let selectedIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: no, inSection: 0)

    let currentCell : CustomCell = table1.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndex)! as! CustomCell

    if currentCell.switch1.on
    {
        currentCell.switch1.setOn(true, animated: true)
    }
    else
    {
        currentCell.switch1.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }

}
```

In switchChanged method you can change state of you array. so you can utilize that array later on.

All the best.

**Update**

Just updated downloadable code with cellForRowAtIndexPath and switchChanged.